# Getting Application is Sending Too Many SMS despite changing sms_outgoing_check_max_count

Tags: sms, adb

I need to send a large number of SMS messages, ~1000, and have edited android's sms_outgoing_check_max_count using the following command:

`adb shell settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 2000`

It didn't work. I got the annoying "Application is Sending Too Many SMS" message.

The phone is a Nokia 3.1+ running Android One 9 and I used the stock messaging app. adb was invoked using Win10 Powershell and the value for sms_outgoing_check_max_count was checked to be 2000. Developer options was turned on this whole time, but the phone has not been rooted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Maybe, you need to change interval?](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/change-android-sms-limit-without-root/)

Comment: @beeshyams Honestly, I can't see how that's important. What I did should enable me to send 2000 messages in 30 minutes, and the whole process takes less than 5. But I'll have to try that in a few days to be sure.

Comment: I am not sure if it helps too, just thought it may be connected in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason. After using

```
adb shell
settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 600
settings put global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms 60000
```

you need to reboot your android phone.

Comment: Restarting the device worked. Accepted the answer.